# The service is currently unavailable. This is a most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by retrying with a backoff

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**Describe the bug**

I am working on an application and it was working fine a few days back but now suddenly it is throwing this error

> [cloud_firestore/unavailable] The service is currently unavailable. This is a most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by retrying with a backoff.

but when I comment out all the firebase related data the application works fine but with firebase connections it throws it error and my application is in production mode over `Google Play`.

**Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.0, on macOS 14.1.2 23B92 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.84.2)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

**Packages I am using in my project:**

```
Dart SDK 3.2.0
Flutter SDK 3.16.0
marshmallow 1.0.0+11

dependencies:
- add_2_calendar 3.0.1 [flutter]
- after_layout 1.2.0 [flutter]
- audio_waveforms 1.0.4 [flutter]
- camera 0.10.5+6 [camera_android camera_avfoundation camera_platform_interface camera_web flutter flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle]
- carousel_slider 4.2.1 [flutter]
- clear_all_notifications 1.0.0 [flutter]
- cloud_firestore 4.8.1 [cloud_firestore_platform_interface cloud_firestore_web collection firebase_core firebase_core_platform_interface flutter meta]
- country_list_pick 1.0.1+6 [flutter]
- crypto 3.0.3 [typed_data]
- cupertino_icons 1.0.6
- custom_pop_up_menu 1.2.4 [flutter]
- dotted_border 2.1.0 [flutter path_drawing]
- emoji_picker_flutter 1.6.3 [flutter flutter_web_plugins plugin_platform_interface shared_preferences]
- face_camera 0.0.8 [flutter camera google_mlkit_face_detection]
- firebase_auth 4.6.3 [firebase_auth_platform_interface firebase_auth_web firebase_core firebase_core_platform_interface flutter meta]
- firebase_core 2.14.0 [firebase_core_platform_interface firebase_core_web flutter meta]
- firebase_dynamic_links 5.3.3 [firebase_core firebase_core_platform_interface firebase_dynamic_links_platform_interface flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- firebase_messaging 14.6.4 [firebase_core firebase_core_platform_interface firebase_messaging_platform_interface firebase_messaging_web flutter meta]
- firebase_storage 11.2.3 [firebase_core firebase_core_platform_interface firebase_storage_platform_interface firebase_storage_web flutter]
- flutter 0.0.0 [characters collection material_color_utilities meta vector_math web sky_engine]
- flutter_chat_bubble 2.0.2 [flutter]
- flutter_facebook_auth 5.0.11 [flutter flutter_facebook_auth_platform_interface flutter_facebook_auth_web facebook_auth_desktop]
- flutter_local_notifications 12.0.4 [clock flutter flutter_local_notifications_linux flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface timezone]
- flutter_multi_select_items 0.4.2 [flutter]
- flutter_neat_and_clean_calendar 0.3.13+28 [flutter intl]
- flutter_rating_bar 4.0.1 [flutter]
- flutter_stripe 9.6.0 [flutter meta stripe_android stripe_ios stripe_platform_interface]
- flutter_svg 2.0.9 [flutter vector_graphics vector_graphics_codec vector_graphics_compiler]
- flutter_switch 0.3.2 [flutter]
- fluttertoast 8.2.4 [flutter flutter_web_plugins]
- geocoding 2.1.1 [flutter geocoding_platform_interface geocoding_android geocoding_ios]
- geolocator 9.0.2 [flutter geolocator_platform_interface geolocator_android geolocator_apple geolocator_web geolocator_windows]
- get 4.6.6 [flutter]
- google_fonts 4.0.4 [flutter http path_provider crypto]
- google_maps_flutter 2.5.0 [flutter google_maps_flutter_android google_maps_flutter_ios google_maps_flutter_platform_interface google_maps_flutter_web]
- google_ml_kit 0.14.0 [flutter google_mlkit_barcode_scanning google_mlkit_digital_ink_recognition google_mlkit_face_detection google_mlkit_image_labeling google_mlkit_object_detection google_mlkit_pose_detection google_mlkit_selfie_segmentation google_mlkit_text_recognition google_mlkit_entity_extraction google_mlkit_language_id google_mlkit_translation google_mlkit_smart_reply]
- google_mobile_ads 3.1.0 [meta flutter visibility_detector webview_flutter_android webview_flutter_wkwebview webview_flutter]
- google_sign_in 6.0.0 [flutter google_sign_in_android google_sign_in_ios google_sign_in_platform_interface google_sign_in_web]
- http 0.13.6 [async http_parser meta]
- image_cropper 4.0.1 [flutter image_cropper_platform_interface image_cropper_for_web]
- image_picker 0.8.9 [flutter image_picker_android image_picker_for_web image_picker_ios image_picker_linux image_picker_macos image_picker_platform_interface image_picker_windows]
- intl 0.18.1 [clock meta path]
- just_audio 0.9.36 [just_audio_platform_interface just_audio_web audio_session rxdart path path_provider async uuid crypto meta flutter]
- path_provider 2.1.1 [flutter path_provider_android path_provider_foundation path_provider_linux path_provider_platform_interface path_provider_windows]
- pay 1.1.2 [flutter flutter_localizations pay_android pay_ios pay_platform_interface meta]
- permission_handler 11.1.0 [flutter meta permission_handler_android permission_handler_apple permission_handler_html permission_handler_windows permission_handler_platform_interface]
- pinput 3.0.1 [flutter smart_auth universal_platform]
- qr_code_scanner 1.0.1 [js flutter flutter_web_plugins]
- qr_flutter 4.1.0 [flutter qr]
- share_plus 7.2.1 [cross_file meta mime flutter flutter_web_plugins share_plus_platform_interface file url_launcher_web url_launcher_windows url_launcher_linux url_launcher_platform_interface ffi win32]
- shared_preferences 2.2.2 [flutter shared_preferences_android shared_preferences_foundation shared_preferences_linux shared_preferences_platform_interface shared_preferences_web shared_preferences_windows]
- sign_in_with_apple 5.0.0 [flutter meta sign_in_with_apple_platform_interface sign_in_with_apple_web]
- spotify_sdk 2.3.1 [flutter flutter_web_plugins logger dio json_annotation js crypto synchronized]
- step_progress_indicator 1.0.2 [flutter]
- swipable_stack 2.0.0 [flutter sprung]
- swipe_cards 2.0.0+1 [flutter]
- swipeable_card_stack 0.0.5 [flutter]
- timeago 3.6.0 [intl]
- url_launcher 6.2.2 [flutter url_launcher_android url_launcher_ios url_launcher_linux url_launcher_macos url_launcher_platform_interface url_launcher_web url_launcher_windows]
- video_player 2.8.1 [flutter html video_player_android video_player_avfoundation video_player_platform_interface video_player_web]
- video_thumbnail 0.5.3 [flutter]
- webview_flutter 4.4.2 [flutter webview_flutter_android webview_flutter_platform_interface webview_flutter_wkwebview]
- zego_uikit_prebuilt_call 3.18.0 [flutter zego_uikit zego_plugin_adapter zego_uikit_signaling_plugin zego_zpns zego_callkit flutter_vibrate audioplayers statemachine uuid permission_handler shared_preferences is_lock_screen2 plugin_platform_interface flutter_callkit_incoming_yoer]
- zego_uikit_signaling_plugin 2.7.2 [flutter zego_plugin_adapter zego_zim zego_zpns zego_callkit flutter_logs plugin_platform_interface]

dev dependencies:
- change_app_package_name 1.1.0
- flutter_launcher_icons 0.11.0 [args checked_yaml cli_util image json_annotation path yaml]
- flutter_lints 2.0.3 [lints]
- flutter_test 0.0.0 [flutter test_api matcher path fake_async clock stack_trace vector_math async boolean_selector characters collection material_color_utilities meta source_span stream_channel string_scanner term_glyph web]

transitive dependencies:
- _fe_analyzer_shared 61.0.0 [meta]
- _flutterfire_internals 1.3.3 [collection firebase_core firebase_core_platform_interface flutter meta]
- analyzer 5.13.0 [_fe_analyzer_shared collection convert crypto glob meta package_config path pub_semver source_span watcher yaml]
- archive 3.4.9 [crypto path pointycastle]
- args 2.4.2
- asn1lib 1.5.0
- async 2.11.0 [collection meta]
- audio_session 0.1.18 [flutter flutter_web_plugins rxdart meta]
- audioplayers 5.2.1 [audioplayers_android audioplayers_darwin audioplayers_linux audioplayers_platform_interface audioplayers_web audioplayers_windows file flutter http meta path_provider synchronized uuid]
- audioplayers_android 4.0.3 [audioplayers_platform_interface flutter]
- audioplayers_darwin 5.0.2 [audioplayers_platform_interface flutter]
- audioplayers_linux 3.1.0 [audioplayers_platform_interface flutter]
- audioplayers_platform_interface 6.1.0 [flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- audioplayers_web 4.1.0 [audioplayers_platform_interface flutter flutter_web_plugins js]
- audioplayers_windows 3.1.0 [audioplayers_platform_interface flutter]
- boolean_selector 2.1.1 [source_span string_scanner]
- cached_network_image 3.3.0 [cached_network_image_platform_interface cached_network_image_web flutter flutter_cache_manager octo_image]
- cached_network_image_platform_interface 3.0.0 [flutter flutter_cache_manager]
- cached_network_image_web 1.1.0 [cached_network_image_platform_interface flutter flutter_cache_manager]
- camera_android 0.10.8+14 [camera_platform_interface flutter flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle stream_transform]
- camera_avfoundation 0.9.13+7 [camera_platform_interface flutter stream_transform]
- camera_platform_interface 2.6.0 [cross_file flutter plugin_platform_interface stream_transform]
- camera_web 0.3.2+3 [camera_platform_interface flutter flutter_web_plugins stream_transform]
- characters 1.3.0
- checked_yaml 2.0.3 [json_annotation source_span yaml]
- cli_util 0.3.5 [meta path]
- clock 1.1.1
- cloud_firestore_platform_interface 5.15.2 [_flutterfire_internals collection firebase_core flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- cloud_firestore_web 3.6.2 [_flutterfire_internals cloud_firestore_platform_interface collection firebase_core firebase_core_web flutter flutter_web_plugins js]
- collection 1.18.0
- convert 3.1.1 [typed_data]
- cross_file 0.3.3+8 [meta web]
- csslib 1.0.0 [source_span]
- dbus 0.7.10 [args ffi meta xml]
- dio 4.0.6 [http_parser path]
- encrypt 5.0.3 [args asn1lib clock collection crypto pointycastle]
- facebook_auth_desktop 0.0.9 [flutter http flutter_secure_storage flutter_facebook_auth_platform_interface]
- fake_async 1.3.1 [clock collection]
- ffi 2.1.0
- file 6.1.4 [meta path]
- file_picker 6.1.1 [flutter flutter_web_plugins flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle plugin_platform_interface ffi path win32]
- file_selector_linux 0.9.2+1 [cross_file file_selector_platform_interface flutter]
- file_selector_macos 0.9.3+3 [cross_file file_selector_platform_interface flutter]
- file_selector_platform_interface 2.6.1 [cross_file flutter http plugin_platform_interface]
- file_selector_windows 0.9.3+1 [cross_file file_selector_platform_interface flutter]
- firebase_auth_platform_interface 6.15.3 [_flutterfire_internals collection firebase_core flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- firebase_auth_web 5.5.3 [firebase_auth_platform_interface firebase_core firebase_core_web flutter flutter_web_plugins http_parser js meta]
- firebase_core_platform_interface 4.8.0 [collection flutter flutter_test meta plugin_platform_interface]
- firebase_core_web 2.8.0 [firebase_core_platform_interface flutter flutter_web_plugins js meta]
- firebase_dynamic_links_platform_interface 0.2.6+3 [_flutterfire_internals firebase_core flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- firebase_messaging_platform_interface 4.5.3 [_flutterfire_internals firebase_core flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- firebase_messaging_web 3.5.3 [_flutterfire_internals firebase_core firebase_core_web firebase_messaging_platform_interface flutter flutter_web_plugins js meta]
- firebase_storage_platform_interface 4.4.3 [collection firebase_core flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- firebase_storage_web 3.6.4 [_flutterfire_internals async firebase_core firebase_core_web firebase_storage_platform_interface flutter flutter_web_plugins http js meta]
- flutter_cache_manager 3.3.1 [clock collection file flutter http path path_provider rxdart sqflite uuid]
- flutter_callkit_incoming_yoer 2.0.0+3 [flutter json_annotation]
- flutter_facebook_auth_platform_interface 4.1.1 [flutter plugin_platform_interface]
- flutter_facebook_auth_web 4.1.1 [flutter flutter_web_plugins js flutter_facebook_auth_platform_interface]
- flutter_local_notifications_linux 2.0.0 [flutter flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface dbus path xdg_directories]
- flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface 6.0.0 [flutter plugin_platform_interface]
- flutter_localizations 0.0.0 [flutter intl characters clock collection material_color_utilities meta path vector_math web]
- flutter_logs 2.1.11 [platform flutter]
- flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle 2.0.17 [flutter]
- flutter_secure_storage 8.1.0 [flutter flutter_secure_storage_linux flutter_secure_storage_macos flutter_secure_storage_platform_interface flutter_secure_storage_web flutter_secure_storage_windows meta]
- flutter_secure_storage_linux 1.2.0 [flutter flutter_secure_storage_platform_interface]
- flutter_secure_storage_macos 3.0.1 [flutter flutter_secure_storage_platform_interface]
- flutter_secure_storage_platform_interface 1.0.2 [flutter plugin_platform_interface]
- flutter_secure_storage_web 1.1.2 [flutter flutter_secure_storage_platform_interface flutter_web_plugins js]
- flutter_secure_storage_windows 2.1.1 [flutter flutter_secure_storage_platform_interface]
- flutter_vibrate 1.3.0 [flutter]
- flutter_web_plugins 0.0.0 [flutter characters collection material_color_utilities meta vector_math web]
- freezed_annotation 2.4.1 [collection json_annotation meta]
- geocoding_android 2.1.2 [flutter geocoding_platform_interface]
- geocoding_ios 2.1.1 [flutter geocoding_platform_interface]
- geocoding_platform_interface 2.0.1 [flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- geolocator_android 4.4.0 [flutter geolocator_platform_interface uuid]
- geolocator_apple 2.3.2 [flutter geolocator_platform_interface]
- geolocator_platform_interface 4.2.0 [flutter plugin_platform_interface vector_math meta]
- geolocator_web 2.2.0 [flutter flutter_web_plugins geolocator_platform_interface]
- geolocator_windows 0.1.3 [flutter geolocator_platform_interface]
- glob 2.1.2 [async collection file path string_scanner]
- google_identity_services_web 0.2.2 [js meta]
- google_maps 6.3.0 [js js_wrapping meta]
- google_maps_flutter_android 2.6.0 [flutter flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle google_maps_flutter_platform_interface stream_transform]
- google_maps_flutter_ios 2.3.3 [flutter google_maps_flutter_platform_interface stream_transform]
- google_maps_flutter_platform_interface 2.4.1 [collection flutter plugin_platform_interface stream_transform]
- google_maps_flutter_web 0.5.4+2 [collection flutter flutter_web_plugins google_maps google_maps_flutter_platform_interface sanitize_html stream_transform]
- google_mlkit_barcode_scanning 0.6.0 [flutter google_mlkit_commons]
- google_mlkit_commons 0.3.0 [flutter]
- google_mlkit_digital_ink_recognition 0.7.0 [flutter google_mlkit_commons]
- google_mlkit_entity_extraction 0.7.0 [flutter google_mlkit_commons]
- google_mlkit_face_detection 0.6.0 [flutter google_mlkit_commons]
- google_mlkit_image_labeling 0.6.0 [flutter google_mlkit_commons]
- google_mlkit_language_id 0.6.0 [flutter google_mlkit_commons]
- google_mlkit_object_detection 0.7.0 [flutter google_mlkit_commons]
- google_mlkit_pose_detection 0.6.0 [flutter google_mlkit_commons]
- google_mlkit_selfie_segmentation 0.3.0 [flutter google_mlkit_commons]
- google_mlkit_smart_reply 0.6.0 [flutter google_mlkit_commons]
- google_mlkit_text_recognition 0.6.0 [flutter google_mlkit_commons]
- google_mlkit_translation 0.6.0 [flutter google_mlkit_commons]
- google_sign_in_android 6.1.20 [flutter google_sign_in_platform_interface]
- google_sign_in_ios 5.7.0 [flutter google_sign_in_platform_interface pigeon]
- google_sign_in_platform_interface 2.4.3 [flutter plugin_platform_interface]
- google_sign_in_web 0.11.0+2 [flutter flutter_web_plugins google_identity_services_web google_sign_in_platform_interface http js]
- html 0.15.4 [csslib source_span]
- http_parser 4.0.2 [collection source_span string_scanner typed_data]
- image 3.3.0 [archive meta xml]
- image_cropper_for_web 2.0.0 [flutter flutter_web_plugins image_cropper_platform_interface js]
- image_cropper_platform_interface 4.0.0 [flutter plugin_platform_interface http]
- image_picker_android 0.8.8+2 [flutter flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle image_picker_platform_interface]
- image_picker_for_web 2.2.0 [flutter flutter_web_plugins image_picker_platform_interface mime]
- image_picker_ios 0.8.8+4 [flutter image_picker_platform_interface]
- image_picker_linux 0.2.1+1 [file_selector_linux file_selector_platform_interface flutter image_picker_platform_interface]
- image_picker_macos 0.2.1+1 [file_selector_macos file_selector_platform_interface flutter image_picker_platform_interface]
- image_picker_platform_interface 2.9.1 [cross_file flutter http plugin_platform_interface]
- image_picker_windows 0.2.1+1 [file_selector_platform_interface file_selector_windows flutter image_picker_platform_interface]
- is_lock_screen2 2.0.1 [flutter]
- js 0.6.7 [meta]
- js_wrapping 0.7.4 [js]
- json_annotation 4.8.1 [meta]
- just_audio_platform_interface 4.2.2 [flutter plugin_platform_interface]
- just_audio_web 0.4.9 [just_audio_platform_interface flutter flutter_web_plugins]
- lints 2.1.1
- logger 1.4.0
- matcher 0.12.16 [async meta stack_trace term_glyph test_api]
- material_color_utilities 0.5.0 [collection]
- meta 1.10.0
- mime 1.0.4
- native_device_orientation 1.2.1 [flutter meta]
- octo_image 2.0.0 [flutter]
- package_config 2.1.0 [path]
- package_info_plus 5.0.1 [ffi flutter flutter_web_plugins http meta path package_info_plus_platform_interface web win32]
- package_info_plus_platform_interface 2.0.1 [flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- path 1.8.3
- path_drawing 1.0.1 [vector_math meta path_parsing flutter]
- path_parsing 1.0.1 [vector_math meta]
- path_provider_android 2.2.1 [flutter path_provider_platform_interface]
- path_provider_foundation 2.3.1 [flutter path_provider_platform_interface]
- path_provider_linux 2.2.1 [ffi flutter path path_provider_platform_interface xdg_directories]
- path_provider_platform_interface 2.1.1 [flutter platform plugin_platform_interface]
- path_provider_windows 2.2.1 [ffi flutter path path_provider_platform_interface win32]
- pay_android 1.0.11 [flutter flutter_localizations pay_platform_interface flutter_svg]
- pay_ios 1.0.9 [flutter pay_platform_interface]
- pay_platform_interface 1.0.3 [flutter yaml]
- permission_handler_android 12.0.1 [flutter permission_handler_platform_interface]
- permission_handler_apple 9.2.0 [flutter permission_handler_platform_interface]
- permission_handler_html 0.1.0+2 [flutter flutter_web_plugins permission_handler_platform_interface]
- permission_handler_platform_interface 4.0.2 [flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- permission_handler_windows 0.2.0 [flutter permission_handler_platform_interface]
- petitparser 6.0.2 [meta]
- pigeon 11.0.1 [analyzer args collection meta path yaml]
- platform 3.1.3
- plugin_platform_interface 2.1.7 [meta]
- pointycastle 3.7.3 [collection convert js]
- process 4.2.4 [file path platform]
- pub_semver 2.1.4 [collection meta]
- qr 3.0.1 [meta]
- rxdart 0.27.7
- sanitize_html 2.1.0 [html meta]
- share_plus_platform_interface 3.3.1 [cross_file flutter meta mime plugin_platform_interface path_provider uuid]
- shared_preferences_android 2.2.1 [flutter shared_preferences_platform_interface]
- shared_preferences_foundation 2.3.4 [flutter shared_preferences_platform_interface]
- shared_preferences_linux 2.3.2 [file flutter path path_provider_linux path_provider_platform_interface shared_preferences_platform_interface]
- shared_preferences_platform_interface 2.3.1 [flutter plugin_platform_interface]
- shared_preferences_web 2.2.2 [flutter flutter_web_plugins shared_preferences_platform_interface web]
- shared_preferences_windows 2.3.2 [file flutter path path_provider_platform_interface path_provider_windows shared_preferences_platform_interface]
- sign_in_with_apple_platform_interface 1.0.0 [flutter plugin_platform_interface meta]
- sign_in_with_apple_web 1.0.1 [flutter flutter_web_plugins sign_in_with_apple_platform_interface js]
- sky_engine 0.0.99
- smart_auth 1.1.1 [flutter flutter_web_plugins]
- source_span 1.10.0 [collection path term_glyph]
- sprintf 7.0.0
- sprung 3.0.1 [flutter]
- sqflite 2.3.0 [flutter sqflite_common path]
- sqflite_common 2.5.0+2 [synchronized path meta]
- stack_trace 1.11.1 [path]
- statemachine 3.3.1 [meta]
- stream_channel 2.1.2 [async]
- stream_transform 2.1.0
- string_scanner 1.2.0 [source_span]
- stripe_android 9.6.0+2 [flutter]
- stripe_ios 9.6.0 [flutter]
- stripe_platform_interface 9.6.0 [flutter freezed_annotation json_annotation meta plugin_platform_interface]
- synchronized 3.1.0
- term_glyph 1.2.1
- test_api 0.6.1 [async boolean_selector collection meta source_span stack_trace stream_channel string_scanner term_glyph]
- timezone 0.9.2 [path]
- typed_data 1.3.2 [collection]
- universal_io 2.2.2 [collection meta typed_data]
- universal_platform 1.0.0+1
- url_launcher_android 6.2.0 [flutter url_launcher_platform_interface]
- url_launcher_ios 6.2.1 [flutter url_launcher_platform_interface]
- url_launcher_linux 3.1.0 [flutter url_launcher_platform_interface]
- url_launcher_macos 3.1.0 [flutter url_launcher_platform_interface]
- url_launcher_platform_interface 2.2.0 [flutter plugin_platform_interface]
- url_launcher_web 2.2.2 [flutter flutter_web_plugins url_launcher_platform_interface web]
- url_launcher_windows 3.1.0 [flutter url_launcher_platform_interface]
- uuid 4.2.1 [crypto sprintf meta]
- vector_graphics 1.1.9+1 [flutter vector_graphics_codec]
- vector_graphics_codec 1.1.9+1
- vector_graphics_compiler 1.1.9+1 [args meta path_parsing xml vector_graphics_codec path]
- vector_math 2.1.4
- video_player_android 2.4.10 [flutter video_player_platform_interface]
- video_player_avfoundation 2.5.3 [flutter video_player_platform_interface]
- video_player_platform_interface 6.2.1 [flutter plugin_platform_interface]
- video_player_web 2.1.2 [flutter flutter_web_plugins video_player_platform_interface]
- visibility_detector 0.4.0+2 [flutter]
- wakelock_plus 1.1.4 [flutter flutter_web_plugins meta wakelock_plus_platform_interface win32 dbus package_info_plus js]
- wakelock_plus_platform_interface 1.1.0 [flutter plugin_platform_interface meta]
- watcher 1.1.0 [async path]
- web 0.3.0
- webview_flutter_android 3.12.1 [flutter webview_flutter_platform_interface]
- webview_flutter_platform_interface 2.8.0 [flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- webview_flutter_wkwebview 3.9.4 [flutter path webview_flutter_platform_interface]
- win32 5.1.1 [ffi]
- xdg_directories 0.2.0+3 [meta path process]
- xml 6.5.0 [collection meta petitparser]
- yaml 3.1.2 [collection source_span string_scanner]
- zego_callkit 1.0.0+2 [flutter uuid plugin_platform_interface]
- zego_express_engine 3.10.3 [flutter flutter_web_plugins js]
- zego_plugin_adapter 2.10.1 [flutter zego_zpns zego_callkit flutter_logs]
- zego_uikit 2.15.1 [flutter zego_plugin_adapter zego_express_engine zego_zpns zego_callkit encrypt permission_handler flutter_logs native_device_orientation wakelock_plus cached_network_image file_picker path plugin_platform_interface]
- zego_zim 2.12.1 [flutter flutter_web_plugins js]
- zego_zpns 2.6.0+1 [flutter flutter_web_plugins js universal_io]
```

Comment: Same here.  I just deployed my Flutter app to the Apple Store (IOS) and started receiving the same error.  What is going on? I am using cloud_firestore: ^4.13.5

Comment: "transient condition" means something has temporarily gone wrong with Firestore and you should keep trying in hopes that the condition is eventually resolved.

Comment: @DougStevenson
I have this application live on google play for android users and I kinda didn't have this option to keep trying

Comment: You also don't have the option of fixing Firestore. The error message is telling you that Firestore is temporarily broken. There is nothing you can do, unfortunately, other than reaching out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) to report a problem.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for the suggestion but it turns out this error was caused by `google_ml_kit` and i don't know how or why. but as soon as I remove this plugin from my application's source code. It starts working again.